# Error al implementar boton con animacion WPF C# usando la libreria Material Design In XAML

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo el siguiente boton:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionLightButton}" Margin="8 0 0 0"
                        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                        materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="{Binding IsSaving}"
                        materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="{Binding SaveProgress}">
                    <!-- simple example of toggling/animating pack icon with a data trigger-->
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Height="24" Width="24">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="materialDesign:PackIcon" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type materialDesign:PackIcon}}">
                                <Setter Property="Kind" Value="CloudSync" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSaveComplete}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Kind" Value="Check" />
                                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.8" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </materialDesign:PackIcon.Style>
                    </materialDesign:PackIcon>
</Button>
```

Que luego de hacer clic muestra una animacion de carga y cuando finalizar debe mostrar un cambio en su icono validando que fue correcto.Este es el modelo que debe implementarse segun la libreria:

```
public class ButtonsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _showDismissButton;
    private double _dismissButtonProgress;
    private string _demoRestartCountdownText;
    private int _orClickMeCount;

    public ButtonsViewModel()
    {
        var autoStartingActionCountdownStart = DateTime.Now;
        var demoRestartCountdownComplete = DateTime.Now;
        var dismissRequested = false;
        DismissComand = new AnotherCommandImplementation(_ => dismissRequested = true);
        ShowDismissButton = true;

        #region DISMISS button demo control
        //just some demo code for the DISMISS button...it's up to you to set 
        //up the progress on the button as it would be with a progress bar.
        //and then hide the button, do whatever action you want to do
        new DispatcherTimer(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100),
            DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new EventHandler((o, e) =>
            {
                if (dismissRequested)
                {
                    ShowDismissButton = false;
                    dismissRequested = false;
                    demoRestartCountdownComplete = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3);
                    DismissButtonProgress = 0;
                }

                if (ShowDismissButton)
                {
                    var totalDuration = autoStartingActionCountdownStart.AddSeconds(5).Ticks - autoStartingActionCountdownStart.Ticks;
                    var currentDuration = DateTime.Now.Ticks - autoStartingActionCountdownStart.Ticks;
                    var autoCountdownPercentComplete = 100.0 / totalDuration * currentDuration;
                    DismissButtonProgress = autoCountdownPercentComplete;

                    if (DismissButtonProgress >= 100)
                    {
                        demoRestartCountdownComplete = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3);
                        ShowDismissButton = false;
                        UpdateDemoRestartCountdownText(demoRestartCountdownComplete, out _);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    UpdateDemoRestartCountdownText(demoRestartCountdownComplete, out bool isComplete);
                    if (isComplete)
                    {
                        autoStartingActionCountdownStart = DateTime.Now;
                        ShowDismissButton = true;
                    }
                }

            }), Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
        #endregion

        IncrementOrClickMeCountCommand = new AnotherCommandImplementation(_ => OrClickMeCount += 1);
        OrClickMeCount = 0;

        //just some demo code for the SAVE button
        SaveComand = new AnotherCommandImplementation(_ =>
        {
            if (IsSaveComplete == true)
            {
                IsSaveComplete = false;
                return;
            }

            if (SaveProgress != 0) return;

            var started = DateTime.Now;
            IsSaving = true;

            new DispatcherTimer(
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50),
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new EventHandler((o, e) =>
                {
                    var totalDuration = started.AddSeconds(3).Ticks - started.Ticks;
                    var currentProgress = DateTime.Now.Ticks - started.Ticks;
                    var currentProgressPercent = 100.0 / totalDuration * currentProgress;

                    SaveProgress = currentProgressPercent;

                    if (SaveProgress >= 100)
                    {
                        IsSaveComplete = true;
                        IsSaving = false;
                        SaveProgress = 0;
                        ((DispatcherTimer)o).Stop();
                    }

                }), Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
        });
    }

    #region Dismiss button demo

    public ICommand DismissComand { get; }

    public bool ShowDismissButton
    {
        get { return _showDismissButton; }
        set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _showDismissButton, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    public double DismissButtonProgress
    {
        get { return _dismissButtonProgress; }
        set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _dismissButtonProgress, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    public string DemoRestartCountdownText
    {
        get { return _demoRestartCountdownText; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _demoRestartCountdownText, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private void UpdateDemoRestartCountdownText(DateTime endTime, out bool isComplete)
    {
        var span = endTime - DateTime.Now;
        var seconds = Math.Round(span.TotalSeconds < 0 ? 0 : span.TotalSeconds);
        DemoRestartCountdownText = "Demo in " + seconds;
        isComplete = seconds == 0;
    }

    #endregion

    #region OrClickMe Demo
    public int OrClickMeCount
    {
        get { return _orClickMeCount; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _orClickMeCount, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }
    public ICommand IncrementOrClickMeCountCommand { get; }

    #endregion

    #region floating Save button demo

    public ICommand SaveComand { get; }

    private bool _isSaving;
    public bool IsSaving
    {
        get { return _isSaving; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _isSaving, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private bool _isSaveComplete;
    public bool IsSaveComplete
    {
        get { return _isSaveComplete; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _isSaveComplete, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    private double _saveProgress;
    public double SaveProgress
    {
        get { return _saveProgress; }
        private set { this.MutateVerbose(ref _saveProgress, value, RaisePropertyChanged()); }
    }

    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged()
    {
        return args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

El boton lo voy a utilizar para login, funciona pero de forma desincronizada con la accion, es de decir el login se produce y no le da tiempo de empezar a cargar la animacion y demas.

Este es el metodo que uso para loguear que se encuentra en el archivo MainWindows.xaml.cs:

```
private void BtnSendCredentials_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CLUsuario cLUsuario = new CLUsuario();
        DataTable login;
        cLUsuario.Nick = nick.Text;
        cLUsuario.Password = password.Password.ToString();
        login = cLUsuario.Login();

        if (login.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow item in login.Rows)
            {
                if (item[5].ToString() == "admin")
                {
                    CurrentUser.Id = Convert.ToByte(item[0]);
                    CurrentUser.Nick = item[1].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.Password = item[2].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.Nombres = item[3].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.Apellidos = item[4].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.Role = item[5].ToString();

                    this.Hide();
                    Dashboard adminView = new Dashboard();
                    DoubleAnimation animFadeIn = new DoubleAnimation();
                    animFadeIn.From = 0;
                    animFadeIn.To = 1;
                    animFadeIn.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                    adminView.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animFadeIn);
                    adminView.ShowDialog();

                    bool?

                resultado = adminView.DialogResult;

                    if (resultado != null)
                    {
                        if (resultado == false)
                        {
                            this.Show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentUser.Id = Convert.ToByte(item[0]);
                    CurrentUser.Nick = item[1].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.Password = item[2].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.Nombres = item[3].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.Apellidos = item[4].ToString();
                    CurrentUser.Role = item[5].ToString();
                    this.Hide();
                    Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
                    DoubleAnimation animFadeIn = new DoubleAnimation
                    {
                        From = 0,
                        To = 1,
                        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                    };
                    welcome.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, animFadeIn);
                    welcome.ShowDialog();

                    bool?

                resultado = welcome.DialogResult;

                    if (resultado != null)
                    {

                        if (resultado == false)

                        {
                            this.Show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El usuario no existe.");
        }
    }
```

Como podría tener acceso desde MainWindows a los elementos que controlan la animacion para poderla sincronizar con el algoritmo de logueo?